# Как в retrofit обработать тело ответа, до обработки его Gson

Tags: json, kotlin, retrofit, gson, обработка

Клиент получает с сайта json ответ типа `{"ключ":"значение"}`. Однако в моем случае значение может содержать лишние кавычки `{"ключ":"значение содержит "лишние" кавычки"}`.
Хочу встроить обработку тела ответа после получения ретрофитом, но до обработки `GsonConverterFactory`. По принципу `HttpLoggingInterceptor` в моем примере.

Т.е. допустим у меня есть функция обработчик `processing()`, которая получает на вход сырой ответ ретрофита, а на выходе дает его же, обработанный внутренней логикой для дальнейшей обработки конвертером Gson.
Подскажите пожалуйста, куда в текущем коде ее можно вставить?

```
class RetrofitInstance(retrofitType: RetrofitType) {

    private val httpLoggInter = HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE)
    private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(httpLoggInter)
        .build()
    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(retrofitType.baseUrl)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

        val siteApi: API = retrofit.create(API::class.java)
}
```

update:

Сделал через изменение полученного ответа с моей модели на Response в API

Было:

```
    interface MySiteApi {
        @GET("RandJSON.aspx?CType=12")
        suspend fun getJoke18(): JokeModel>
    }
      

  suspend fun getJoke18Z(): JokeModel {
            return RetrofitInstance.mySiteApi.getJoke18()
        }
```

Стало:

```
interface MySiteApi {
    @GET("RandJSON.aspx?CType=12")
    suspend fun getJoke18(): Response<ResponseBody>
}

    suspend fun getJoke18Z(): JokeModel {
        val response = RetrofitInstance.mySiteApi.getJokeTest()
        val responseString = response.body()?.string()
        // здесь обработчик полученной строки
        val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
        val gsonConverted : JokeModel = gson.fromJson(responseString, JokeModel::class.java)
        return gsonConverted
    }
```

Но, хотелось бы более элегантного решения. Какой-то свой ConverterFactory чтоли? Или это слишком сложно реализуется?

Comment: Перепишите метод API интерфейса, чтобы получать либо сырой ответ либо строку вместо JSON. А в JSON самостоятельно конвертируйте. Самый простой вариант.

Comment: @eugene-krivenja Благодарю за ответ. Так и сделал.

Comment: Свой конвертер имеет смысл, если все ответы приходят не по стандарту.